# Open FZF in current directory of file I am viewing

Tags: vimrc, plugin-fzf, fzf

Often I am in some 'general' directory when I open files, such as `~` or `Desktop`. `FZF` by default opens the user's `pwd`, for example, if I have:

```
Desktop $ vim ~/.vim/vimrc
```

And I do:

```
:FZF
```

It will search in `Desktop` by default. How can I pass a parameter equivalent to:

```
:FZF dir(current_file)
```

Or:

```
:FZF expand('%:p:h')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:Files [PATH]` for this. See the [command reference](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim#commands).

To pass in the directory: `:Files %:p:h`

Alternatively, you can also use `lcd` to change the directory for the current window, then use FZF as normal.

Comment: Welcome Michael!

Comment: Thanks @D.BenKnoble :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in accepted reply, to expand the solution I add

`nnoremap <Leader>pf :Files %:p:h<CR>`

to ~/.vimrc

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Welcome! You might want to add `<silent>` to your normal mode mappings that call Ex commands, such as this one. So that they don't print (or quickly flash) the command being executed. See `:help :map-silent` for details.